# Latching an analog signal on a trigger event

Tags: analog, latch, analog-switch

I am looking for sort of an analog equivalent of regular digital latches. I want it to mirror its input (voltage) to its output (voltage, with or without gain) only at a trigger edge/pulse and maintain this output until another trigger event. Basically, an analog flip flop.  Instead of holding one digital bit, it holds an arbitrary voltage level. I believe I can design such circuit myself using opamps and switches, but I was wondering if there is a standard way of accomplishing this. I had a brief research, but all I found was clamping/protection circuits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for either a "track and hold" or a "sample and hold" circuit.

Traditionally these were used in front of ADC's to increase the effective analog bandwidth of the ADC.